# How to check if an array field contains a unique value or another array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb now.

I have a blogpost collection, and it has a `tags` field which is an array, e.g.

```
blogpost1.tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5']
blogpost2.tags = ['tag2', 'tag3']
blogpost3.tags = ['tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5']
blogpost4.tags = ['tag1', 'tag4', 'tag5']
```

How can I do these search

1. contains `tag1`
2. contains `['tag1','tag2']`
3. contains any of `['tag3', 'tag4']`

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Try this out:

```
db.blogpost.find({ 'tags' : 'tag1'}); //1
db.blogpost.find({ 'tags' : { $all : [ 'tag1', 'tag2' ] }}); //2
db.blogpost.find({ 'tags' : { $in : [ 'tag3', 'tag4' ] }}); //3
```

Comment: This is well documented in the help: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24all

Comment: for the $all does it mean all elements AND in the expressed order or is it just unordered ?

Comment: @ScottHernandez I do not see that they mention that the field you are using as your search can be an array, and how that is handled. "field : { $in : array }". What happens when you search for an array within an array of arrays? Not specified.

Comment: Is there any INDEXING we can do on array's to stop duplicate?
If yes, please guide how.

Comment: @Jeff the Bear: Can you please provide the equivalent Java code? I am having great difficulty in getting the Java equivalents of these MongoDB Queries.

Comment: @redben its unordered like written in the docs: [$all operator DOCS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_all). Just read the example part and you will see.

Comment: @Jeff the Bear: db.blogpost.find({ 'tags' : { $in : [ /tag/ ] }}); 
in above query i am trying to match regex exp,when i am trying the same using node js,the variable 'tag' is creating the query like this below:
db.blogpost.find({ 'tags' : { $in : [ /'78438'/ ] }}); 
hence it is not working but when i remove the quotes surrounding the value it works,so how to solve this problem

Answer (score 5):

My experience is that for (2) the following solution is much faster than the one with "$all":

```
db.blogpost.find({ $and: [ {tags: 'tag1'} ,{tags: 'tag2'} ] });
```

but to be honest, I do not not why. I would be interested in, if anyone knows.

Comment: By the way, just tested it on indexed keywords list. Absolutely the same result with $and and $all

Comment: Maybe that changed with newer versions in the meantime.

Comment: It's circumstantial. For the "$and", mongodb making a logical "and" operation. Therefore if the first expression is false, the second are not taken into consideration. This means less processing.

Comment: But that should happen with '$all' also, shouldn't it!?

Comment: $all is probably two lookups on an index, $and is probably one lookup with a sequential scan on the result.