# $setIsSubset for regular queries in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am looking to do the equivalent of `$setIsSubset` http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/ for regular (i.e. NOT aggregate) queries in MongoDB.  How can I do this?

Assume that I have the documents

```
{ 'x' : ['A', 'B'] }
{ 'x' : ['A', 'D'] }
```

And that

```js
filter = ['A', 'B', C']
```

I want to do a 
`find({"x" : {'$setIsSubSet':filter}})` and expect only to get back

```
{ 'x' : ['A', 'B'] }
```

It seems like most conditional commands match *any* not *all.*  I also want it to be a subset, so it seems that `$and` and `$all` would not match `[A,B]` to `[A,B,C]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try the following in the shell:

```
var filer = ['A', 'B', 'C']
db.coll2.find({x: {"$not": {"$elemMatch": {"$nin" : filer }}}})
```

Output

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("54f4d72f1f22d4a529052760"), "x" : [  "A",  "B" ] }
```

Comment: That double negative is so bizarre, but like you said, it works.  I wonder what the performance is on it?

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could modify this so that if `x` contained an array of arrays (i.e. [ ['A', 'B'] ]) instead of just an array of elements?  I'd like to unroll the array of arrays and match individual elements like before and not have to match arrays.

Comment: Is there a way to write the above query in Spring Data JPA  ?