# MongoDB: $all with empty array...

Tags: mongodb, find

I'm running a query on a collection with documents like these.

```
{"name": "Daniel", "tags": ["person", "owner", "father"]},
{"name": "Jane", "tags": ["person", "owner", "mother"]},
{"name": "Jimmy", "tags": ["person", "owner", "son"]}
```

Now, if I want to find all documents matching the tags person AND owner I would do something like this

```
var match = ['person', 'owner'];
model.find({'tags': {$all: match}});
```

Now I need to do the following:

1. When match has values, return all document matching those (This is done)
2. When match is empty [ ], return all documents.

What's the most efficient way to do that in a single query?

Thanks in advance,

D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to add the condition in your application layer, and keep your `query` that gets executed on the server very simple.

- If the `match` array has one or more elements, add a query field to
  your query `condition`, else execute an empty condition which would
  return you all the documents.

snippet:

```
var match = ['person', 'owner'];
var condition = {};
if(match.length > 0){
   condition["tags"] = {$all:match};
}
db.model.find(condition);
```

Having said this, with the [**$all**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator, it is not possible to achieve both the conditions in a single query.

> The $all operator selects the documents where the value of a field is
>   an array that contains all the specified elements.

Comment: It is surprising that `model.find({'tags': {$all: []}})` does not return all documents (assuming tags exists as an empty array in each document).