# combining two $elemMatch queries with AND boolean operator in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have two distinct *mongoDB* queries that represent two different conditions, for example:

```
{ stuff: { $elemMatch: { foo: 1, bar: "a" } } }
```

and:

```
{ stuff: { $elemMatch: { foo: 2, bar: "b" } } }
```

where `stuff` is an array of elements that have both `foo` and `bar` fields set.

Now, I am not sure how to match elements in the collection that meet at the same time the two aforementioned conditions.

Just to be clear: in this case I need to get all elements that have both one element of `stuff` that has  `foo` set as `1` with `bar` set as `"a"` and also one element of `stuff` that has `foo` set as `2` with `bar` set as `"b"`.

Doing  `{ stuff: { $elemMatch: { foo: { $in: [1, 2] }, bar: { $in: ["a", "b"] } } }` is wrong, since it will behave like an `OR` on the two expression (and including two new expressions).

Any idea on how to `AND` them?

Comment: not really sure what you want to accomplish. How can `stuff.foo` be equal to `1` and `2` at the same time? That's only possible if `foo` is an array. In that case, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366687/how-to-check-if-an-array-field-contains-a-unique-value-or-another-array-in-mongo

Comment: @mnemosyn: hmm, maybe it is. Thanks for the pointer! :)

Comment: @mnemosyn: so, maybe is it: ``{ stuff: { foo: { $all: [1, 2] } } }`` ? But what if I have another field, like ``bar`` inside elements of ``stuff`` ? (I will update the question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Just to be clear: in this case I need to get all elements that have both one element of stuff that has foo set as 1 with bar set as "a" and also one element of stuff that has foo set as 2 with bar set as "b".

I hope I got it. Shouldn't that be

```
db.coll.find({ $and: [ 
                  { "stuff" : { $elemMatch : { "foo" : 1, "bar" : "a" } } },   
                  { "stuff" : { $elemMatch : { "foo" : 2, "bar" : "b" } } } ]});
```

?

Comment: Any way to use the `$and` inside `$elemMatch`, instead of the other way around like in this answer?