# matching ALL values in an array (making $in inclusive?)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have a collection of blog posts. Each blog post has a field called `tags`, which is an array of strings.

When I retrieve these posts, I pass an array of tags called `requirements`. **I want to make sure each post I get back has each tag from `requirements`**.

Concretely, if I have 2 posts, 1 with tags #fun #stuff and the other with #stuff #doing, and I pass the array `['fun, 'stuff']` then I should only get the first post back.

`$in` does exactly what I'm trying to do, but isn't inclusive (it matches *any* value; I need to match *all* values).

I suppose I could dynamically construct queries using `$and`, but that seems clunky.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I think [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366687/how-to-check-if-an-array-field-contains-a-unique-value-or-another-array-in-mongo) is more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, actually, that's exactly what I need. Sorry. I searched, promise! :)