# MongoDB querying with the array of value

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have user schema

```
{
phone:'String'
}
```

My query field is phone and i have an array of phone numbers like this `['1233','2134','43433']` to query;

I had to query user collection that this phone numbers are present or not in collection...

I wanted to complete this operation in single  query rather then using async.each or some asynchronous operation.

Is it possible with single operation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an array field contains a unique value or another array in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366687/how-to-check-if-an-array-field-contains-a-unique-value-or-another-array-in-mongo)

Comment: take a look at $in operator, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: guys phone is not an array @Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$in` operator to find by **phone**

```
User.find({ phone : { $in : ['1233','2134','43433'] }}, function(err, users) {
  if(err) {
     //return error
  }
  console.log(users);
  //return success
});
```