# Mongodb Match value of array object by Query Method?

Tags: mongodb

The example collection I have

```
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "name" : "John",
    "height": 170,
    "favorite" : {
        "fruits" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "banana",
                "reason" : null
            },
            {
                "name" : "orange",
                "reason" : null
            }
        ],

    }
},
{
    "_id" : "456",
    "name" : "Cena",
    "height" : 160,
    "favorite" : {
        "fruits" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "berry",
                "reason" : null
            },
            {
                "name" : "orange",
                "reason" : null
            }
        ],

    }
}
```

The array value I get from JS is `["banana","orange"]` , I join them become `banana,orange` and pass it for matching. It must exactly match all the value from the collection and the return value should be the `"_id":"123"`, if the value is `banana,orange,berry` result should be NONE.

I tried the `Matches`

```
string q_value = "banana,orange"; // exmaple
IMongoQuery query = Query.And(
                    Query.GTE("height",170),
                    Query.Matches("favorite.fruits", q_value)
);
MongoCursor mongocursor = db.GetCollection("XXDB", "Member").Find(query);
```

But I think `Matches` is not the one I'm looking for.

This [How to check if an array field contains a unique value or another array in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366687/how-to-check-if-an-array-field-contains-a-unique-value-or-another-array-in-mongo?rq=1) maybe is the way, but it is not query method, in this question the query I looking for is just one of the query in my function.

Help me if anyone know the query method, THANKS A LOT

Comment: I have edited my question, and it is not duplicate.

Comment: @chridam I have edited my question, it is different